# How to find the number of intervals contained in an interval?

Tags: geometry

Let $n$, a positive integer, so that $n + 1$ is the number of intervals given.
Let $x, y$ be positive integers with the added restriction that $x \le y$.
All intervals are of form $[x, y]$.

Given two intervals $[x, y]$ and $[x', y']$. We say that $[x', y']$ is included in $[x, y]$ if and only if $x \le x'$ and $y' \le y$.

Given an interval $[x, y]$ we call $x$ the **start** of the interval and $y$ the **end** of the interval.

Let $I$ be a set of the $n + 1$ given intervals.
Let $I_1, I_2, ..., I_{n + 1}$ be the 1st, 2nd, ..., (n + 1)th intervals.

Let $a, a', b, b', r$ be nonnegative integers.

$a$ is the number of intervals that have their end **less or equal** to the start of $I_1$.
Example:
[image: Example_a]

In this example $I_2$ has its end less or equal to the start of $I_1$ so $a = 1$.

$a'$ is the number of intervals which have the start **greater or equal** to the end of $I_1$.

$b$ is the number of intervals which have their start **less** than the start of $I_1$.

$b'$ is the number of intervals which have their end **greater** than the end of $I_1$.

$r$ is the number of intervals included in $I_1$.

My question is: Can you find out the value of $r$ by finding a relation between $a, a', b, b', r$ that holds for all $n$-sized sets of intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, seems unlikely. The idea seems to be that you're trying to understand how many intervals lie in $I_1$ just using information about the starts and ends of all intervals, but never using information about which end belongs to which start. So the philosophy behind breaking this idea would be to find a scenario where we have a set of intervals which give rise to the same ends and starts, but where changing "what end belongs to what start" changes the value of $r$. An example:

$$I_1 = [0,3], \, I_2 = [-1, 2], \, I_3 =[1,4], \\
I_1 = [0,3], \, I_2 = [1, 2], \, I_3 =[-1,4].$$

As you can see, in both situations the set of ends and beginnings are the same, so we have

$$a = 1, \, a' =1, \, b = 1, \, b' = 1$$
in both situations. But in the first scenario, $I_1$ contains none of the two other intervals and $r = 0,$ and in the second one, only $I_2$ is contained in $I_1$, so $r = 1$.